# extracting features for HOG

Tags: python, numpy, feature-extraction

I am trying to extract features from a dataset that contains images. For this i will be using the HOG concept. But while running the code i am getting this error

```
   features = np.array(filename,'int16')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'train.csv'
```

This is my code:-

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import cv2
import csv
from csv import reader
filename = "train.csv"
fields = []
rows =[]
csvfile = open("train.csv",'r')
csvreader=csv.reader("train.csv")
features = np.array(filename,'int16')
```

Comment: If it probably because you file contains non integers. First read as float and then cast to int16 if you need that format. e.g. features=np.array(filename,'float32') and then features=features.astype(np.int32)

Comment: [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) does not accept a filename as an argument.  It is not a function that reads data from a file.  Take a look at [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) and [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).

Comment: Thank you , both of the suggestions helped :)